# Strange issue with jQuery.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, liferay, portlet

I'm having a strange behaviour with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function get() 
            {
                alert("gggg");
                jQuery.get (
                    "http://localhost:8080/c/portal/json_service", 
                    {
                        serviceClassName: "com.liferay.test.service.TrabajadorServiceUtil",
                        serviceMethodName: "findByName",
                        servletContextName: "TrabajadorPlugin-portlet",
                        serviceParameters: "[param]",
                        param : document.getElementById("nombre")
                    }
                );
            }
</script>

<div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" value="<%=searching%>"/>
    <input type="button"  value="Submit" onClick="javascript:get()"/> 
</form>
</div>
```

Liferay portal gets blocked when the button "Submit" is pressed. The pop-up with the message "gggg" is showed, but after click ok on it, the page becomes blocked.

If I remove the line 'param : document.getElementById("nombre")', it doesn't block.

Can anyone explain me where is the error, or the reason of this behaviour?

Thanks in advance,

Rafa

Comment: Should be `document.getElementById("nombre").value`, but I'm not sure if that causes the failure.

Comment: what you want to put in your `param` variable?

Comment: What do you mean by blocked ?

Comment: Yeah, of course, .value is responsible. Is a String. Blocked means that the tab of chrome being used gets blocked, can't refreshed, can't be blocke... nothing. Just wait til gets "broken", and then I can refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pass an entire DOM element as the value for `param`, which jQuery isn't going to like. What type of element has ID `nombre`, and what property from that element do you want? If it's some kind of input, you likely want the `value` property, so you'd do:

```
param : document.getElementById("nombre").value
```

Comment: Yes, is a String, .value was the problem. Thanks a lot, just a problem of being now 7 hours at work. ;)

Comment: A last question, how can I store the value returned by the server after sending the get request with that code to show it in the portlet?? THanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

Thinking this through a little more, you should probably do this in a different way altogether. You're sending the data when the user clicks on the submit button, but remember if a user hits enter while typing in the input text box the form will submit but your code will not catch that.

A more robust solution would be to do it this way instead:

```
<div>
  <form id="nombre_search">
    <input type="text" id="nombre" value="<%=searching%>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
  </form>
</div>​

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nombre_search").submit(function(){
      $.get("http://localhost:8080/c/portal/json_service", {
        serviceClassName: "com.liferay.test.service.TrabajadorServiceUtil",
        serviceMethodName: "findByName",
        servletContextName: "TrabajadorPlugin-portlet",
        serviceParameters: "[param]",
        param : $("#nombre").val()
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Changes to your code:**

- Added an id to the form.
- Made the submit button a `submit` button instead of just a `button`.
- Placed code inside `$(document).ready` block.
- Code runs when `form` is submitted not when `button` is clicked.

Hope this helps,
Sandro

Comment: Hi Sandro, thanks for your answer. I pasted your code and it's giving error at onClick="return get();"
The function is not called get() anymore with your code, isn't it? The error says: "Cannot return from outside a function or method."

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say, that happens with the commented code, not with my renewed function.

Comment: I updated my answer. The reason for the `get` function being undefined probably has to do with how it's declared on the page. You shouldn't define functions with `function get() {}` instead do `var get = function() {};` or `window.get = function() {};`. The last two examples are more predictable across all browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandro, quite helpful ;)